# $A:X \to Y$- linear continuous function, $A\neq 0$ $H=\ker A\implies \exists z \in H^{\bot}: \|z\|=1$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis, functions

$A:X \to Y$- linear continuous function, $A\neq 0$ $H=\ker A, X=H\oplus H^{\bot}\implies \exists z \neq 0 \in H^{\bot}: \|z\|=1$

This implication is confusing to me, here in the book it says in brackets: Since $A$ is continuous $A^{-1}(0)$ is closed (this fact i understand), how this conclusion($\implies \exists z \neq 0 \in H^{\bot}: \|z\|=1$) I frankly do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $X$ is a Hilbert space.

We only need $H^\perp\ne\{0\}$, as if it contains any nonzero $z_0$ vector, we can take $z:=\displaystyle\frac{z_0}{\|z_0\|}$.

And, in case of Hilbert spaces, $H^\perp\ne\{0\}\ \iff\ \bar H\ne X$ where $\bar H$ is the closure of $H$, and it happens to be $\bar H=H^{\perp\perp}$.

If $A$ was not continuous, still $A\ne 0$, then $H=\ker A$ might be *dense*, and then $H^\perp=\{0\}$.